# How to check if a listener event is a passive event?

Tags: javascript, dom, w3c, dom-events

I'm writing a gesture/action library that also manages event listeners and triggering. I have implemented my lib to support gesture objects setting passive listeners via an API that looks like this: `this.on('touchstart.passive', this.startHandler, { reject: errorHandler })`. My lib supports multiple gestures, setting multiple listeners, both passive and non-passive. The lib will make sure at most only one *real* listener will be attached to the DOM. So we can at most have 2 `touchstart` listeners, where one is passive and the other is not.

My question and issue, is that I can not detect if a received event was attached with the `{ passive: true }` option. I thought that I could use the `cancelable` property on the native event object, since it is an error to call `preventDefault()` on a passive event. But the `cancelable` property is always true, even if the browser will throw an error on `preventDefault()`.

I have read the [WhatWG DOM standard on event listeners](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#observing-event-listeners) and made some tests in Firefox and Chrome but can't find any information about how to distinguish the two types of events.

It is significant for my library, since a passive event listener is keyed with a `".passive"` post-fix, e.g. `"touchstart.passive"` vs `"touchstart"`.

How to I check the received DOM event for passive option, so I can trigger the right internal listeners?

EDIT

Currently the gist of my flow for attaching listeners is:

```
function eventNotifier(event) {
    this.fire(event.cancelable ? event.type : event.type + '.passive', new GestureEvent(event))
}

addEvent(el, realEventName, eventNotifier, options)
nativeListeners.set(eventName, 1)

function addEvent (el, type, listener, options) {
    el.addEventListener(type, listener, options || true)
}
```

*where `nativeListeners` is a `Map` that keep track of real event listeners*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test the value of `event.defaultPrevented` after the call to `event.preventDefault();`. The browsers will throw warnings/errors for the call if it is a passive event, however it doesn't halt execution of the javascript. So the following should work:

```js
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    // This is not a passive event
  } else {
    // This is a passive event
  }
}, { passive: true });
```

I found the inspiration for this answer in this link: https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md

Comment: After reading your edit, I understand this is not what you are after. You are looking for a way to determine before the event happens if it is passive or not, correct?

Comment: No your answer was in the right direction. I opted for a different approach though because it was simpler to implement. I simply have 2 `eventNotifier`'s. One for passive and one for regular events. I attach the passive `eventNotifierPassive` for passive events, so I don't need to test the native event. But it would make sense if the following line would work: `addEventListener('wheel', e => { if (e.cancelable) e.preventDefault() }, { passive:true })` Sadly, Chrome will have `cancelable` to true if there is another non-passive listener listening for the same event name/type.

Answer (score -3):

Write an if statement to check if the listener has ".passive" attached.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense in this context. What you're suggesting is that there is no standard way to detect passive events and I should re-write my architecture to somehow know if a event was attached with the `{ passive: true }`. That breaks my single event-notifier call path but might be the only solution. I'm afraid though that you just made a suggestion out of thin air that has nothing to do with your knowledge about the DOM event listener standard or current browser implementations.